# How to avoid polling for time-consuming async REST requests?

Tags: rest, asynchronous, polling

The question is on how to design a REST web service which performs time-consuming jobs (order of magnitude of several seconds and minutes).

The fastest solution would be to proceed as follows:

1. client sends a POST request to server (POST /job), the answer has
   HTTP status 202 and will contain the job id;
2. client asks periodically the job status with a GET (e.g. `GET /job/:id/status`);
3. when the job completes the client requests the results with a GET (e.g. `GET /job/:id/result`).

What I don't like is step 2 because with many jobs in progress the server is unnecessarily overloaded.
To avoid this I thought two other solutions:

- when the client does the first POST request, it gives also a URL which can 
  be used as a *callback* from the server. When the server ends the
  elaboration, it will notify the client at this URL with a GET/POST 
  request;
- the server makes available a [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) where the client can register 
  and get "notifications" on job completion;

All the three solutions have aspects that I do not like:

1. ***polling:*** server overload;
2. ***callback:*** client must make a URL available to the server;
3. ***websocket:*** why introduce another "tecnology" to the REST webservice?
   Perhaps, at that point, it is better to use only websockets to do
   all requests.

Are there other solutions? If no, which of the three you would consider more reliable?

Comment: You always have the option to rate-limit clients that poll to frequently. Your suggestion furthermore requires the client to also work as a server so that the actual server can take the role of the client. This somehow violates the client-server paradigma. If you need constant back and forth communication REST isn't the right architecture for you, I guess.

Comment: Good question....

Answer (score 4):

Polling tends to be very easy to implement and it can be very reliable. The reliability comes from the simplicity of the solution. Polling requests should be very cheap requests in general. Polling can be made efficient by backing off the polling frequency and by checking more than one job at a time (e.g. send 1000 IDs in one request).

Any non-polling solution must be a form of active notification. The HTTP callback solution you proposed requires the client to have a web server running. It can be done but it seems unnecessary.

The web socket idea clearly works as well. You will need reconnect logic and handle the case that the job completes while the client happens to be disconnected. Client-side code will likely involve threading since you probably don't want one web socket connection per job.

A simpler idea than using web sockets would be to use a "comet" HTTP request. The server keeps the HTTP request open until the job completes. This can be very efficient with async IO so that no thread is blocked while waiting. But if the connection is severed some reconnect strategy must be implemented.

You could make the server write a message to a queue that the client reads.

All of these notification solutions tend to be much more complicated than the simple polling solution. They need more developer time and will break in production more often. But they can have lower latency and use less resources. I'd try to make polling work. Likely it will work and you're done quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You almost answered your question by yourself. The thing is, what approach would you choose based on your requirements. All of your proposals are solutions for your problem, but you have to put weight on them and decide for yourself. However I think you put too much exaggeration on method 1. If you develop a progression strategy, like doing the poll (not pool) irregularly, say first poll after 30 seconds, next one after 20 more, then after 10, then after 5, then maybe repeat that sequence, then it won't be that stressful for the server.

Also, the intervals you choose may be based on the response from the POST request if you can somehow predict the complexity of the job. So if the job would take minutes, no point in polling every 5 seconds for example. You may develop a strategy like an array (time in seconds): [300, 120, 60, 30, 20, 10], meaning you would wait 5 minutes first, then another 2 minutes, then 1 minute, etc. - you get it, and you can finish with intervals of 10 seconds. Since the job itself could take minutes, I don't think it is critical if the result gets delayed by some seconds, i.e. ready, but not served right on time.

Comment: Polling with smartness should improve the efficiency and it could be a starting point. Thank you also for the idea to give the polling schedule on the first POST answer. PS: thanks for pointing out the typo, I correct immediately